# Make days from "showOtherMonths" clickables (datepicker)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

By default, the days displayed after the end of the current month or before the start of the current month, are disabled and unclickable.

[image]

I need to make them clickable as other days of the current month

Jsfiddle :

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w2x005e6/

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set `selectOtherMonths` option to true as you can see in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#other-months). The code:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
  });
});
```